# React Ajax setInterval Memory leak

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs, memory-leaks

I looked and tried everything in the other questions.  Still couldn't solve my memory leak. Here's the code. Essentially it gets a JSON file from a server and updates the table accordingly.  It loops the AJAX call every 5 seconds.

Memory leak happens in this AJAX call.
Any help would be great.

LoadDataTable: function(){

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "***************************.json",
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  success: function(data) { 
   this.setState({temp1:data[2].field3}),
   this.setState({temp2:data[2].field5}),
   this.setState({temp3:data[2].field25}),
   this.setState({temp4:data[2].field26});

     if(data[2].field3 > 9 || data[2].field5 >9||data[2].field5>9 ||data[2].field26>9){
        document.location.href='#/'
   }
   else{
       //console.log("Stopped playing");
   }
   setTimeout(this.LoadDataTable, 5000);


}.bind(this),
  error: function(request, status, err) {

    //request.abort();
    console.log(request);
    setTimeout(this.LoadDataTable, 5000);

  }.bind(this),

 })

},
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.LoadDataTable();
    //this.setInterval(this.LoadDataTable, 100);// Call a method on the mixin
},
```

Comment: This isn't the answer but you don't need to call setState multiple times, pass a whole object once

Comment: I would say that, generally speaking, you wouldn't want your React component to be responsible for making these AJAX requests. Ideally you'd be using Redux (or some external state mechanism) to make the requests, and then your app would pass the new data to the component as a `prop`. A side effect of using that architecture is that it would avoid the memory leak you encounter -- plus it's more in line with React "best practices".

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your success and error functions out to a named function like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "***************************.json",
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  timeout: 5000,
  success: this.successTimeout,
  error: this.errorTimeout,
})

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.LoadDataTable();
  //this.setInterval(this.LoadDataTable, 100);// Call a method on the mixin
},

successTimeout(data) { 
  this.setState({temp1:data[2].field3}),
  this.setState({temp2:data[2].field5}),
  this.setState({temp3:data[2].field25}),
  this.setState({temp4:data[2].field26});

  if(data[2].field3 > 9 || data[2].field5 >9||data[2].field5>9 ||data[2].field26>9){
     document.location.href='#/'
  }
  else{
    //console.log("Stopped playing");
  }

  setTimeout(this.LoadDataTable, 5000);
}.bind(this),

errorTimeout(request, status, err) {
  //request.abort();
  console.log(request);
  setTimeout(this.LoadDataTable, 5000);
}.bind(this)
```

Also, you might want to think about using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). Just be sure to [include the polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for browser compatibility